# C++ : BreakPointing into into library "lib" files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I currently have a project say `projA` that uses a library project that I created. Now here is the scenario. I have two instances of Visual Studio open: instance one and instance two. One instance fires up `projA` and other has the library solution loaded up with breakpoints set. Nothing else is done at instance two. Now here is the problem when `projA`(instance one of VStudio) starts the breakpoints in the other instance of visual studio are never triggered. The only way through which I could step through the library code is to break-point into the function that calls the library code in `projA`(instance one) and then step into the library code which also opens up code from the library in instance one. What I want to do is put breakpoints in instance 2 and have breakpoints triggered there. Any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the breakpoint in the VS instance that's debugging the EXE. All your breakpoints should be set in the same instance. Even if the source code is not part of the open project, Visual Studio uses the debugging symbols to know where your source files are. So, you can open a source file and set a breakpoint in the other instance.